# Not abe to declare as timestamp in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select *
From #####
where username   in ('akhil')   and between (now()  ::timestamp and now()  - interval '1 day'::timestamp)
```

Getting error in this line .
Error - cannot cast type interval to timestamp without time zone .

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the second cast.  You need a column name.  Something like this:

```
select * 
from #####
where username in ('akhil') and
      <some date column> >= now() - interval '1 day' and
      <some date column> < now();
```

Comment: Thanks . Worked Perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

the error is in the second cast

```
now() - interval '1 day'::timestamp
```

is interprested as.

```
now() - (interval '1 day')::timestamp
```

when you actually mean

```
(now() - interval '1 day')::timestamp
```

or possibly you mean

```
now()::timestamp - interval '1 day'
```

both are valid, but the the result you'll get when daylight saving starts or stops is different (hint `interval '1 day'` is the same as `interval '24 hours'` in the first)

There's a strong possiblity that you should actually be using `timestamp with time zone` for the database column.